# How can I change some variables before building in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developping an API and an Unity application in local environnement. So, in Unity, actually I hardcoded my calls to the api with a string containing `localhost/api`. I'm wondering how can I change this hardcoded string before a build ( without doing this manually ) so I can use the real domain of the API only in the case I build for production.

And is there a way to define an "environment" build, like `production`, `staging` ? Wit this, if I build for `staging`, the domain of the staging api will be used.

For C#/Unity readers that know JS, this type of issue would be resolved by using multiple .env files, like `.env.staging` `.env.local`, `env.production`, all of them containing the right api adress, depending to the build environnement. In the JS code, I could get the api adress only by typing `process.env.API_ADDRESS`

Thanks!

Comment: Application.isEditor?

Comment: If I need to test a build in a local environnement, with the game builded that call my localhost API, it will not work :/

Comment: Create a file in your game folder and only run debug code if that file exists. That way it only works on your PC. An alternative would be to make a boolean that you check against and use globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define you own ones or use the UNITY_EDITOR one :D

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_preprocessor_directives